# Sample code for image upload

Tags: android

In would like to write a simple Android application that takes a picture from the camera and uploads it to a webserver. Additionaly, I would like it to print in the screen the response from the server wich is a simple text string.

Do you know if there is any sample code that does something like that?

Thank you,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

look this page http://me.sylvek.net/index.php?2009/02/11/434-api-facebook-with-android.

Sylvain